# How to initialize STM32F401 DMA SPI Slave with an empty FIFO Tx? (Or how to flush it?)

Tags: stm32, spi, dma, fifo

I am using the DMA SPI as slave on a STM32F401. I use:

```
DMA SPI SlaveHAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hspi2, pTxData, pRxData, len};
```

When I do this a len amount of zeros is written to the FIFO Tx. For my use case I need to write to the Tx buffer using serial communication. I can successfully write to the Tx buffer using serial but when I try to retrieve this data using a SPI master, the initial zeros are first in line.

Is it necessary to write on the FIFO Tx when initializing DMA SPI? Is there a way to avoid this? If this is the expected behavior, how to FLUSH the FIFO Tx to avoid reading this unwanted data?

I found 2 answers on how to flush the FIFO Tx but they are too vague for my little knowledge. A solution from https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkeT8/stm32f0-spi-txfifo-flush suggests:

1. Reset SPI in RCC
2. Complete init SPI

And another one from https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkhXo/dma-fifo-flush-issue says:

1. Manually loading the first word from into the DR of the SPI channel
2. Configuring the DMA channel to start at the next word in my buffer
   (obviously reducing the length by 1 word)

Are these the way to go? If so, I could use some more explanation on how to go about with the implementation of these.